# Strange problem with proximity sensor on Nexus 5X

Tags: nexus-5x, proximity-sensor

A few days ago I started experiencing a strange problem with my proximity sensor. When I answer a call and put the phone to my ear, the screen goes blank.  When the call ends, the screen stays black.  This (as I've discovered) happens to quite a few people.

I started checking with aida64 app. When the app starts, it reports proximity sensor value of 5cm.  When I cover the sensor, the value goes to 0.  Then I uncover the sensor - and the value stays at 0.  I switch from aida64 to any other app and back to aida64 - and the value goes back to 5cm.  Alternatively, I can 
switch the screen off, then on again - and the value will go back to 5cm. Basically, it looks like once the value is down to 0, it won't reset for the currently running activity/app - yet it does reset when the activity is deactivated and then reactivated.

I tried booting in safe mode - same results.

Any ideas about trying to solve this?

The phone is Nexus 5X with PureNexus 7.1.2 ROM and Magisk.  Come to think of it, it may have started when I updated magisk a few days ago, but maybe not.  Any suggestions on rolling magisk back a couple of versions would also be useful.

*EDIT:* I uninstalled magisk altogether and the problem persists, so it can't be magisk related.

Comment: The proximity sensor bases on optical recognition. The sensor is usually located next to the speaker in the upper border of the phone. Using another smartphone camera digital camera or a webcam you can see the LED that creates the light detected by the proximity sensor. Make sure this area is clean and the display glass is full intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. As I didn't have much to loose, I opened the phone up and found HUGE amounts of dust inside, including around the proximity sensor.  The whole sensor was just clogged with dust. I took out all the tiny parts, gaskets, etc., carefully cleaned everything with a soft brush and re-assembled the phone. Voila! Everything works correctly now.

I suspect the dust was getting in the way of the light in the proximity sensor - but it wasn't fully closed due to the dust moving around there.